# React error boundary gets invoked but does not render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

[Please see this codesandbox for reproduction](https://codesandbox.io/s/error-boundary-issue-k5zp1?file=/src/index.js)

I have created an error boundary that redirects the app to the `/error` route. However, sometimes when an error is triggered (in the case of the codesandbox by clicking on the link for the bug page), my error boundary is invoked and the browser is redirected to the `/error` route but the component that should show on `/error` does not show / render and instead I just see a white screen. What is wrong and why is the error boundary getting invoked such that it redirects the browser but rendering does not complete? Thanks!

**index.js:**

```js
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import ErrorBoundary from "./errorBoundary";
import "./index.css";

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/bug">Page with Bug</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/bug">
        <BugPage />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/error">
        <ErrorPage />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/">
        <HomePage />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </div>
);

const HomePage = () => <h1>Home Page</h1>;

const ErrorPage = () => <h1>This is the error boundary</h1>;

const BugPage = () => {
  const dummyData = {
    foo: {
      id: 1
    }
  };

  return <h1>{dummyData.bar.id}</h1>;
};

const Spa = () => (
  <Router>
    <ErrorBoundary>
      <App />
    </ErrorBoundary>
  </Router>
);

render(<Spa />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**errorBoundary.js:**

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

export class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      hasError: false,
      hasRedirected: false
    };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error) {
    this.setState({ hasError: true });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      this.props.history.push("/error");
    }
    return this.props.children;
  }
}

export default withRouter(ErrorBoundary);
```

Comment: can you just use the `componentDidCatch()` to call `this.props.history.push('/error')`?

Comment: @Anthony, this worked! Mind posting as an answer so I can give you points and credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use `componentDidCatch()` to call your re-direct, i.e.

```
componentDidCatch(error) {
  this.props.history.push('/error');
}
```

I'm not entirely sure if calling a function like that in `render()` is valid or not, but you could also do:

```
render() {
  return this.state.hasError ? <SomeErrorComponent /> : this.props.children;
}
```